# Remove line with one or two digits using php

Tags: php, regex, replace

I tried to delete lines that have one or two characters.

Ex:

```
text text
11
0
text
```

Result:

```
text text
text
```

I used `$text = str_replace('/^(.{2})', 'dsfsdfsd', $text);` but not work.

What's wrong?

Comment: You have to check your regular expression. The regex you specified matches the beginning of a string followed by two characters with no limitation. You have to build a more precise regular expression and adjust the matching behavior to your needs. There a plenty of tools available to help writing regular expressions, for example https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str-replace) does not accept regular expressions. It is a needle/haystack search and replace function. Meaning it seeks the string *literal*.

For regular expression search/replace use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace) instead.

If you'd like remove any line of text that contains exactly 1 digit or exactly 2 digits, for example, you could use the following regular expression with `preg_replace`.

```
$text = '
text text
11
0
text
';

$text = preg_replace('/^\d{1,2}$/m', '<replaced>', $text);

echo $text;
/**
 * This should give you ...
 * 
 * text text
 * <replaced>
 * <replaced>
 * text
 */
```

Here `\d` means any digit character `[0-9]` in [PCRE](http://php.net/pcre) and the bracketed `{1,2}` just means match either 1 digit or 2 digit characters. Remove the caret and sigil from this expression would cause it to match any 1 or 2 digit character expression found in the subject. Here it looks for an exact match on each line where the `m` pattern modifier allows the PCRE engine to go into multi line mode. You can read more about [PCRE pattern syntax in the manual](http://php.net/pcre.pattern) as well.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}/i", 'sometext', $text);

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested, for regular expressions, you need to use `preg_replace`. Below example works perfectly on your input.

```
<?php
    $text = "Lorem Ipsum\nDolar\n2\nContan\n23";
    $after = preg_replace("/[\n][0-9]{1,2}[\n]{0}/", "", $text);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Before : \n".$text."\n\n";
    echo "After : \n".$after;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

In regex number is represented by `d` (including all languages), otherwise you can use `[0-9]{2}` or `\d{2}`.

Comment: str_replace doesn't use regular expressions and the user asked for chars